# How to run MapBox under Blazor?

Tags: mapbox, blazor

I try to run MapBox under Blazor , using the next library

```
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js
```

When I delete the line (from default app)

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

MapBox library works , except events. When i restore that line  then events works, but the map disappear

How to fix the problem?

**_host.cshtml:**

```
@page "/"
@namespace BlazorApp3.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlazorApp3</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />


    <style>

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 85%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </app>

    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGVyZW50ZXYiLCJhIjoiY2sycDN1Z21zMDBheTNrbzZ2aG42aWUyMiJ9._2hucdk7L6jhzEHE6LGv9A';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/terentev/ck2so0c4h1q5x1cqow0aj9nh8',
            center: [34.047, 63.779],
            zoom: 4.41
        });
    </script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
<div id='map'></div>
```

Did so:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

<div id='map'></div>

@code {
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("mapBoxFunctions.initMapBox");
    }
}
```

P.S. I noticed that despite the fact that the site seems to work fine, but in the console you can see an error at startup [image]
Can't anybody say how to fix the problem.
After publishing the application - no error is visible in the browser

Comment: When you remove that line then Blazor won't work anymore...

Comment: Are you properly adding the map? What does that code look like?